# How to update gitlab merge request with curl? Getting 401 all the time

Tags: gitlab-ci

Need to update labels in merge request during gitlab ci. Tried different variants:

```
curl -X PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/merge_requests/134?access_token={token}&labels=merged
```

Tried passing token as header and as data. 
Tried passing "personal_token", "access_token", "token" and etc.

Getting {"message":"401 Unauthorized"} all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use private_token as it said on documentation:

```
curl https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=<your_access_token>
```

or in the header, as you said:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxx" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects"
```

Have a look on the official page:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personal-access-tokens

Example:

Getting information from merge request with iid 1(the actual labels are testlabel and testlabel3):

```
#curl -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/11209705/merge_requests/1?private_token={XXXXXX}
{"id":28761206,"iid":1,"project_id":1120970.......,"labels":["testlabel","testlabel3"],...}
```

Sending put with curl with "--data" and the parameter to update "labels" to "test":

```
# curl -X PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/11209705/merge_requests/1?private_token={XXXXX} --data "labels=test"
```

Getting information from merge request with iid 1(the actual labels is "test"):

```
#curl -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/11209705/merge_requests/1?private_token={XXXXXX}
    {"id":28761206,"iid":1,"project_id":1120970.......,"labels":["test"],...}
```

Comment: Not clear. Should I make request like in your example to get session, and proceed further requests without adding token?

Comment: ```
curl https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=token
{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects"
{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}
```

Comment: Have a look to your token on your user, and try to regenerate the token marking the scope API and try again, updating my answer

Comment: curl --header "ACCESS-TOKEN: token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/11811662/merge_requests/136?labels=merged" - didn't failed, but at the same time label wasn't added.

Comment: updating my answer to show that it works with a python example

Comment: No more failures, but labels are not updating. Currently I need curl example for updating labels, not python. curl -X PUT fails with 401, while GET doesn't fail.

Comment: added PUT with updating label example

Comment: Again 401
curl -X PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/11811662/merge_requests/134?private_token=token --data "labels=merged"

Get is working well (becuase it returnes data), but PUT gets 401 all the time.

Comment: New token helped.